# Access subreport in where condition

Tags: ms-access, filter, subreport

I would like to open a report with the docmd.openreport function and filtering it by a value (date format) from its subreport.

What is the right syntax to access this subreport in my where clause?

I've tried with Mitarbeiterhonorare_Unterbericht.Datum, [Mitarbeiterhonorare_Unterbericht]![Datum] and several other notations but I just don't seem to get it right...

report: Mitarbeiterhonorare, subreport: Mitarbeiterhonorare_Unterbericht, field to access: Datum

Thank you very much in advance!

```
WhereCondition:="[....] AND [x] BETWEEN #" & Format(Me.Datum_von, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "# AND #" & Format(Me.Datum_bis, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
WhereCondition:="[Datum] BETWEEN #" & Format(Me.Datum_von, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "# AND #" & Format(Me.Datum_bis, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"
```

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately, it then asks me after the parameter value for "Datum"

Comment: Then Datum isn't the name of the field you try to filter on. Only you will know what it could be.

Comment: It is, I double checked now... Any other ideas?

Comment: I see you mention _subreport_. If so, and Datum is from the subreport, you can't filter the report this way.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame... Any other ideas how i could combine these two reports and then filter by both date fields in the reports?

Comment: To be honest, I have a hard time figuring out what the purpose might be. I think you need to rethink your concept.